# How to get distance by road through Google Map API

Tags: android, routes, google-maps-android-api-2, distance

I want to get distance by road by foot and by car in my app.I have already got distance by line but now I want the exact distance. I have read to enable billing for google account for API key and I have done that. Now I couldn't understand he code I have seen multiple and tried them but can't understand how to use the API available at google guide. Sometimes the app crashes and sometime it gives nothing in response.
On priority what I want to do is to get the exact distance only it can be on foot or on vehicle any. Any help will be very grateful
The last code which I tried but its doing nothing

```
origin = new LatLng(currentLat, currentLong);
                    dest = new LatLng(donarLat, donarLong);
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl();
                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                    downloadTask.execute(url);

 private String getDirectionsUrl() {
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + currentLat + "," + currentLong;
        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + donarLat + "," + donarLong;
        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String key = "key=" + "**********NR9TxLUwXyeq0jwV6k************";
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;
        // Output format
        String output = "json";
        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urlList) {
            try {
                ArrayList<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String url : urlList) {
                }
                return returnList;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
                return null; // Failed, return null
            }
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results) {
            super.onPostExecute(results);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            for (String url : results) {
                parserTask.execute(url);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {
        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
            try {
                ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();

                // for (String url : jsonData) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[i]);

                    DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                    routes = (ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>) parser.parse(jObject);
                }
                return routes;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background task", e.toString());
                return null; // Failed, return null
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            if (result.size() < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(DonarList.this, "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {

                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
                String distance = "No distance";

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    if (j == 0) {
                        distance = point.get("distance");
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                Log.d("Distance: ", distance);
                Toast.makeText(DonarList.this, "Your Distance ya hy :" + distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Comment: as per the documentation, you should be using the `DistanceMatrix API` so the request format url is like _maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/outputFormat?parameters_ while yours is using **directions**?

Comment: I'm trying to find some solution already solved the same issue or even I get some idea from that how to use it .I have already searched and checked a lot of blog but neither of them helped

Comment: have you checked the documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro It is billed though..

Comment: Yes I have checked that, Iam new to coding to I didn't understand that Iam searching for some code which Has implemented same thing